# License management systems or packages to use for licensing our software

Tags: open-source, software-development

I'm working on a pre-study to replace a legacy software platform built around the start of 2000. The platform contains a lot of mixed functionality and could preferably be cut up in pieces to a micro service architecture.

One of the core components of this solution is a home made licensing management system. The company produces and sells software and licenses to these software are managed from this system. The licensing used is the classic 90's CD-key approach.

We are now investigating how to change this to a more modern subscription model.

Pay per use
Pay as you go
...and so on. We tend to approach software as a service as licensing model.

License management is not the company's core business so if there are any other solutions than to build our own it would be preferable.

Now to the question, I believe that there must be solutions/software already built to support this licensing stuff that we can buy or subscribe to, open source packages we can integrate, instead of building our own licensing system once more. I haven't managed to find any providers supporting this.

Are there any "license as a service" systems or providers that could support this or any open source packages to use? The new platform will run on Azure using .NET.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are various licensing systems that work with different code. For example, try [ArmDot](https://www.armdot.com/) or its analogs.
Some time ago I was looking for some kind of library for creating and checking licenses. But still did not find anything suitable.